# utf8 and php error

Tags: php, utf-8

when i enter a pound symbol - £ - into my code it appears as an unknown symbol... its in the code and doesnt go into the db.

im using codeigniter, notepad++ on windows and have added

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
```

to the top of my page-

Pound symbols that go in and out of the db seem to be fine but when the symbol is hard coded, i get the error symbol.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: here's what I suspect... you've pasted the pound sterling _ascii_ code into your file http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/pound-sign-symbol-pound-sterling-ascii-code-156.html ... this is byte 156, which is *not* utf8. The utf8 pound sterling is made of two bytes: http://hexutf8.com/?q=c2a3 ... and as you can see if you try sending byte 156 (9C in hex) alone it is invalid http://hexutf8.com/?q=9c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the php file ( where you whant to hardcode the pound simbol ) document encoding to utf-8 . If that doesn't work you can allways use `&pound;` or `&#163;` witch you're browser will render as a pound sign .

Comment: Also make sure your DB is set to deal with utf8 encoding!

Answer (score 1):

Your source-file is probably not encoded in UTF-8. The easiest method is to change the encoding of that file. Notepad++ can convert it for you, as far as i remember.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<head>` make sure you set

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Also try the MySQL statement

```
 SET NAMES 'utf8'
```